# Calculating the mean and sd of a lognormal distribution from the log mean and log 5th percentile

Tags: normal-distribution, quantiles, lognormal-distribution

I have a mean and 5th percentile value from river flow data that are assumed to follow a log-normal distribution. From these, I need to calculate the the mean and SD of the underlying normal distribution.

I know how to do this with the mean and SD of the lognormal distribution by using the method of moments:

```
# 'lg_' prefix indicates it belongs to a lognormal distribution

mean = np.log(lg_mean / ((1 + ((lg_sd**2) / (lg_mean**2))) ** 0.5))
sd = (np.log(1 + (lg_sd**2) / (lg_mean**2))) ** 0.5
```

But I don't know how to do it with only the mean and 5th percentile. Interestingly, I found an equation in a piece of Fortran code from the 70s that does what I want:

```
sd = (2.7057 + 2 * np.log(lg_mean / lg_05)) ** 0.5 - 1.6469
mean = np.log(lg_mean) - 0.5 * sd**2
```

I tested it using random data and it works (although it seems to have a small residual error that could be due to decimal points). I suspect the function uses a combination of the method of moments and z-scores to calculate the values, but so far I haven't been able to demonstrate the solution.

Does anyone know how this solution works? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: The application of MM is obscure, at best, because this is purely an algebra problem: given the expressions for the mean and and percentile of a lognormal distribution in terms of the geometric mean and geometric sd, simply solve for the latter.

Comment: The `1.6469` looks as if it should be closer to `1.644854` (which would round to  `1.6449`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the (as yet unknown) mean and standard deviation of the underlying normal $\mu$ and $\sigma$, so $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$,

and the (known) mean of the lognormal $m_Y$ with $5$th percentile value $Y_{(0.05)}$, where $Y=e^X$.

Then we should have $m_Y=\exp(\mu+\frac12\sigma^2)$ and  $Y_{(0.05)} = \exp(\mu+ \Phi^{-1}(0.05) \sigma)$ where $\Phi^{-1}(0.05)$, is the $5$th percentile value of a standard normal, about $-1.644854$

i.e. $\log(m_Y)=\mu+\frac12\sigma^2$ and $\log(Y_{(0.05)})=\mu+ \Phi^{-1}(0.05) \sigma$

which would suggest $\sigma=\sqrt{\Phi^{-1}(0.05)^2+2\log(m_Y) - 2\log(Y_{(0.05)}) } +\Phi^{-1}(0.05)$ i.e. $$\sigma=\sqrt{2.705543+2\log(m_Y) - 2\log(Y_{(0.05)}) }-1.644854$$  which is close to the code you quote, though not exactly the same. I suspect my expression will remove most of your residual error.

You can then find $\mu$, with any of $\mu=\log(m_Y)-\frac12\sigma^2$ or $\mu=\log(Y_{(0.05)})-\Phi^{-1}(0.05) \sigma$ or $$\mu=\log(Y_{(0.05)})+1.644854 \sqrt{2.705543+2\log(m_Y) - 2\log(Y_{(0.05)}) }-2.705543.$$

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation @Henry